# Blender 2.79 won't insert keyframe

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I am following a [guide](https://medium.com/hackers-and-makers/how-to-draw-animations-in-blender-f51e98c07647) for the Grease Pencil, however I cannot add keyframes as per step 2?

I hover the mouse cursor over the Dope Sheet and select All Channels. Nothing seems to happen.

I then select Grease Pencil Draw, however I am unable to draw.
[image: My drawn image in Frame0/1?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the setup for a frame by frame animation.

Check Continuous Draw and Onion Skin.

After you draw something, move to the next frame and hit  <kbd>D</kbd> , then  <kbd>B</kbd> . This will create an Empty Frame where you can draw something else.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helped and worked.  Although, frames > 1 still have frame 1's image, which I would like to only be an onion skin on frame2, so I can redraw frame2's animation.  Only the Filament layer changes to an onion skin in frame2 and is removed in frame3, however all other layers remain.  (not sure if related, but I can't Erase the Printer frame layer which holds the filament, which I drew too wide).